# Nginx Virtual Host not redirecting properly, both sites redirect to first listed server in sites-enabled configuration

Tags: nginx, dns, redirect, virtualhost

I'm having a problem getting Nginx to recognize and redirect two different domain names (specifically `www.webapptest1.tk` and `www.webapptest2.tk` hosted on **Freenom**) to separate `index.html` files in different folders.

Here's my file structure and Nginx `sites-enabled` configuration:

**Webapptest1 HTML**

Directory: `/var/www/webapptest1.tk/html/index.html/`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>indexTest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>Welcome to webapptest1</h1></center>

    <center><p>This webpage domain name is redirecting to the IP address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx</p></center>

    <center>Webapptest1 successfully redirected!</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Webapptest2 HTML**

Directory: `/var/www/webapptest2.tk/html/index.html/`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>indexTest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>Welcome to webapptest2</h1></center>

    <center><p>This webpage domain name is redirecting to the IP address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx</p></center>

    <center>Webapptest2 successfully redirected, and is NOT serving the same file as Webapptest1!</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Nginx sites-enabled Virtual Host configuration**

*Note: For the purpose of testing, I didn't symlink a file from sites-available*

```
# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.


server {
    listen 80;

    server_name webapptest1.tk;

    root /var/www/webapptest1.tk/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name webapptest2.tk;

    root /var/www/webapptest2.tk/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

On Freenom (the domain provider I'm using), I've set both domain's to URL Forward to the Nginx server by IP address like so:

[Webapptest1 URL Forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X54n4.png) (Similar for Webapptest2)

Now, visiting either www.webapptest1.tk or www.webapptest2.tk, I'm getting Webapptest1's `index.html` page.

Thing is, I've tested with modifying my local `hosts` file to include the Nginx server IP as well as both domain names. In this instance, both links were redirected to their respective `index.html` pages. Without the `hosts` file modification, both links show only Webapptest1's `index.html` page.

I take it the problem is on Freenom's end and the way it's redirecting the URL's, and not my Nginx server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By configuring URL forwarding as you did,the page shown in your browser is the one you will see if you go to http://35.192.230.223/ (which is the first virtual host in your nginx configuration).
All you need is to configure simple `A` records:

```
webapptest2.tk       A    35.192.230.223
www.webapptest2.tk   A    35.192.230.223
webapptest1.tk       A    35.192.230.223
www.webapptest1.tk   A    35.192.230.223
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, that worked for me. Configured the `A` record for `www` and both links were redirected properly.